# Input javascript code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what i want is when i click on deluxe i want all the options to be checked so fog lights leather and DVD but it doesn't work.. I have no clue what is wrong with my jquery :/ Please help and also when i click on an option let's say i want fog lights it will automaticaly check the custom one

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>A basic form</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .form-field {
            clear: both;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 350px;
        }
        .form-field label {
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .form-field input {
            float: right;
            width: 150px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        #submit {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>a basic form</h1>
    <hr>
        <form action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
            Car trim and package information
            </legend>
            <div class="form-field">
            
            <div>Package:</div>
                <input id="plain" type="radio" name="trim" value="plain">
                <label for="plain">Plain</label>
            <input id="deluxe" type="radio" name="trim" value="custom">
                <label for="deluxe">Deluxe</label>
                <input id="custom" type="radio" name="trim" value="custom">
                                                                <label for="custom">Custom</label> 
                
                
                
                
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
            <div>Extra Options:</div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="foglights" name="option">
                <label for="foglights">Fog Lights</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="leather" name="option" value="leather">
                <label for="leather">Leather</label>
              </div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="dvd" name="option" value="dvd">
                <label for="dvd">DVD</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form">
            </div>
            
            
            
            
            
       
            
            
            
            </fieldset>
        
        
        </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(documet).ready(function() {
            $("input[name="trim"]").click(function(event) {
                if ($(this).val() == "deluxe") {
                    $("input[name="option"]").attr("xxxxxxxxxxChecked", true);
                }else if ($(this).val() == "plain") {
                    $("input[name="option"]").attr("Checked", false);
                }
            });
            $("input[name="option"]").click(function(event) {
                $("#custom").attr("Checked", "Checked")
            }
        });
        
        
        
        
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: first use `document` instead of `documet`

Comment: _“I have no clue what is wrong with my jQuery”_ — check your browser console, hit F12. You also need to write attribute selectors like this: `$("input[name='option']")`.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the string when you are asking jQuery to fetch the DOM Element.

Here's your issue:

```
$("input[name="trim"]")
```

Which should be:

```
$('input[name="trim"]')
```

See that I switched the surrounding `"` (double-quotes) for `'` (single-quotes)? You are doing this multiple times in your code, so you will have to find and fix it in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>A basic form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .form-field {
            clear: both;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 350px;
        }
        .form-field label {
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .form-field input {
            float: right;
            width: 150px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        #submit {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>a basic form</h1>
<hr>
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Car trim and package information
        </legend>
        <div class="form-field">

            <div>Package:</div>
            <input id="plain" type="radio" name="trim" value="plain">
            <label for="plain">Plain</label>
            <input id="deluxe" type="radio" name="trim" value="deluxe">
            <label for="deluxe">Deluxe</label>
            <input id="custom" type="radio" name="trim" value="custom">
            <label for="custom">Custom</label>




        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <div>Extra Options:</div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="foglights" name="option">
            <label for="foglights">Fog Lights</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="leather" name="option" value="leather">
                <label for="leather">Leather</label>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="dvd" name="option" value="dvd">
            <label for="dvd">DVD</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form">
        </div>









    </fieldset>


</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='trim']").click(function(event) {
            if ($(this).val() == "deluxe") {
                $("input[name='option']").attr('checked', true);
            }else if ($(this).val() == "plain") {
                $("input[name='option']").attr("checked", false);
            }
        });
        $("input[name='option']").click(function(event) {
            $("#custom").attr("Checked", "Checked")
        });
    });




</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hello, i edited my answer, replace all your code with it

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in the code, like clousures and selectors at JQuery function. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='trim']").click(function(event) {
        if ($(this).val() == "deluxe") {
            $("input[name='option']").attr('checked', true);
        }else if ($(this).val() == "plain") {
            $("input[name='option']").attr("checked", false);
        }
    });
    $("input[name='option']").click(function(event) {
        $("#custom").attr("Checked", "Checked")
    });
});
```

```css
            .form-field {
                clear: both;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 350px;
            }
            .form-field label {
                float: left;
                width: 150px;
                text-align: right;
            }
            .form-field input {
                float: right;
                width: 150px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            #submit {
                text-align: center;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>a basic form</h1>
<hr>
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Car trim and package information
        </legend>
        <div class="form-field">

            <div>Package:</div>
            <input id="plain" type="radio" name="trim" value="plain">
            <label for="plain">Plain</label>
            <input id="deluxe" type="radio" name="trim" value="custom">
            <label for="deluxe">Deluxe</label>
            <input id="custom" type="radio" name="trim" value="custom">
            <label for="custom">Custom</label>

        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <div>Extra Options:</div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="foglights" name="option">
            <label for="foglights">Fog Lights</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="leather" name="option" value="leather">
                <label for="leather">Leather</label>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="dvd" name="option" value="dvd">
            <label for="dvd">DVD</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form">
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First error:

```
$("input[name="trim"]")
```

When you use the same symbol (i.e.: ") in a string you must escape it or you may use another symbol:

```
$("input[name=\"trim\"]")
```

or

```
$('input[name="trim"]')
```

The error is: "input[name="trim"]" --> first string: input[name=  plus symbol trim plus  the string ]: no meaning.....

The second error:
you want to test the label text and not the radio button value: so you need:

```
$('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text().toLowerCase()
```

Because the test is case sensitive you need to lowercase the whole string.

The third error is:

```
attr("Checked", false);
```

The property is "checked" (lowercase) and for such property you must use:

```
prop("checked", false);
```

The event for radio or checkbox is change and not click.

So the final result is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name=\"trim\"]").change(function(event) {
    var lblTxt = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text().toLowerCase();
    if (lblTxt == "deluxe") {
      $("input[name=\"option\"]").prop("checked", true);
    }else if (lblTxt == "plain") {
      $("input[name=\"option\"]").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
  $("input[name=\"option\"]").change(function(event) {
    $("#custom").prop("checked", this.checked)
  });
});
```

```css
.form-field {
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 350px;
}
.form-field label {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
.form-field input {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}
#submit {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>a basic form</h1>
<hr>
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Car trim and package information
        </legend>
        <div class="form-field">

            <div>Package:</div>
            <input id="plain" type="radio" name="trim" value="plain">
            <label for="plain">Plain</label>
            <input id="deluxe" type="radio" name="trim" value="custom">
            <label for="deluxe">Deluxe</label>
            <input id="custom" type="radio" name="trim" value="custom">
            <label for="custom">Custom</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <div>Extra Options:</div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="foglights" name="option">
            <label for="foglights">Fog Lights</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="leather" name="option" value="leather">
                <label for="leather">Leather</label>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="dvd" name="option" value="dvd">
            <label for="dvd">DVD</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```